# Hide element by class in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the following code, but it [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7bn/207/). Any idea where I have gone wrong?

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('appBanner').style.visibility='hidden';
```

```html
<div class="appBanner">appbanner</div>
```

Using jQuery or changing the HTML is not possible as I am using `[self->webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""];` in Objective-C.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. You need something like: document.getElementsByClassName('appBanner')[0].style.visibility='hidden';

Answer (score 162, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`(an array-like object) of all elements matching the class name. The `style` property is defined for `Element` not for `HTMLCollection`. You should access the first element using the bracket(subscript) notation.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('appBanner')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7bn/208/)**

To change the style rules of all elements matching the class, using the Selectors API:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.appBanner'), function (el) {
  el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

If `for...of` is available:

```
for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.appBanner')) el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: fedeetz/Atanas Korchev provide a more direct answer 24AUG2013. Preferred.

Comment: Note that this will only hide the first element with class name 'appBanner'

Comment: I would go for `display` instead of `visibility`

Answer (score 52):

```
var appBanners = document.getElementsByClassName('appBanner');

for (var i = 0; i < appBanners.length; i ++) {
    appBanners[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

[**JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SkfDz/)

Comment: I beginner on JS, but why you write `, i;` on first line? This used in for cycle? ( but we declare `i` in cycle later ) Or it small mistake? Or maybe its some "best practice"? Could you comment it, please.

Comment: @DenisSavenko it's simply declaring a second var.

Comment: @DenisSavenko - It's valid `var` syntax to declare multiple variables separated by commas, but in this case it is a mistake to then *also* declare `i` with `var` in the `for` loop - though this doesn't actually cause an error, it's just untidy.

Comment: cute answer bro...i like it

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('appBanner'), function(elem){ elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'; });
```

**Forked** @http://jsfiddle.net/QVJXD/

Comment: FYI: Array.filter is not a JS function.  Looks like this uses Mootools.

Comment: `Array.Filter' doesn't work with Javascript

Answer (score -4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.appBanner').fadeOut('slow');

        });
    </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.appBanner').hide();

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The OP does not mention jQuery

Comment: <script>
  function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("left");
   if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName('sj-vm-filter')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
   } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName('sj-vm-filter')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
  }
 </script>