# how to hide class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to hide class with javascript . I get a value if status = 1 then the class show, and if status = 2 then the class is hidden.

```
<div class="entry-img" id="status">
  <img id="txt_img_content_1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Comment: you want to hide the div or just remove the class, you can use toggle or show or hide

Comment: Where's the value of `status` coming from?

Comment: This may help with finding your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18414401/13566068

Answer (score 1):

I thing, that toggle might be to use in your case:

```js
function setStatus(status) {
    document.querySelector("#status").classList.toggle("entry-img", status == 1);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.entry-img {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
<button onclick="setStatus(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="setStatus(2)">2</button>
```

Comment: we  don't use a button click, just want to display a class that use a status with value which is called using ajax

Comment: it was just an example to show, how it works. Just look inside the example-function "setStatus". The code "<dom-element>.classList.toggle(<css-class>, <flag>)" is simple and you controll, if the css-class is added by the flag (true=add, false=remove).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the code something like this.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("status");
if(status==2){
  element.classList.remove("entry-img");
}
if(status==1){
  element.classList.add("entry-img");
}
```

For more information you can refer to this links https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: also, if you get an element, it won't be a number

Answer (score 0):

```
var divElement = document.getElementById("status");
if(status==2){
  divElement.classList.remove("entry-img");
}
if(status==1){
  divElement.classList.add("entry-img");
}
```